# Change value on element click JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, magento, click

We have a widget in our Magento page which allows us to show some featured products. But what our main goal is, is that we want to change the featured products when an element is clicked, here is what the widget looks like in code:

```
{{widget type="slideshow/slideshow" slideshow_ids="16,17,18,19,20" template="ma2_slideshow/slideshownews.phtml"}}
```

The id's which the widget uses, needs to be changed when an element is clicked.
I've already searched and fiddled with some variables but it doesn't work unfortunately...
I am also wondering what type of language the widget is...

Any more information needed? Any suggestions?